# Dynamically resizing text view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on a simple trivia app. The main screen uses a text view to allow for larger questions than what could fit in a text field. The problem with this, is that the text view is unsightly when it's larger than the question. I already can do a limited form of dynamic resizing by counting the amount of characters in the string, and resizing it that way. However, sometimes this doesn't work perfectly as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJYCe.png);
also if it's taken to another device besides an iPhone X, the resizing will be way off.

Is there a way for me to count the number of lines in a text view after text wrapping?

Comment: Are you using a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` because it may have so much text it needs to scroll?

Comment: Why not UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

You can set constraints on your text view. In your case it would look something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

This particular constraint sets the textView max height equal to half the views size.

Here's a good guide to auto layout that explains how constraints work from Apple,
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/